# Trying to pass custom field in checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In below code you can see that I want to display a value if it already exists in Database.

I am getting order id as well as the values i have echo.
But when i use this in value, it results Empty.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

    function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $filters = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );

     $loop = new WP_Query($filters);
     $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
     echo $key_1 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_dist', true );
     echo $key_2 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true );
     echo $key_3 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_lane', true );
     echo $key_4 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_alley', true );
     echo $key_5 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_num', true );
     echo $key_6 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_floor', true );

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Delivery Address') . '</h2><p>' . __('Enter your address to ensure it is in the area of our delivery service') . '</p>';
     woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_street', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-srt-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Street'),
            'value' => get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true ),
            'show'  => 'true',
            'placeholder'   => __('Street'),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_street'));
    echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Does this echo the correct value? 

echo $key_2 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true );

Comment: yes, it is giving true results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this instead:

```
 woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_street', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-srt-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Street'),
        'show'  => 'true',
        'placeholder'   => __('Street'),
     ), get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true ));
```

Comment: Not working. Any other idea? 
and one more query
$checkout->get_value( 'my_field_street'));

Comment: $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_street'));

Comment: You said that get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true ); has the correct value right?

Comment: yes, get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_my_street', true ); This gives true value, i used the code you given. But it also does not display any value in input field of street.
What i am trying to do is if the value already exist in database it should display that value otherwise we have to allow user to enter new street address to this field.

Comment: What does echo $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_street') show?

Comment: your code works,, thanks may be browser having some cache. Could you please help me bit more. What if need to show value for select box.

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
 'type'  => 'select',
 'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
 'label'         => __('City'),
 'options'     => array(
 'Taipei' => __('Taipei', 'woocommerce' )
 )), get_post_meta( $orid, '_billing_my_dist', true ));
What i should suppose to do for select box ?

Thanks in Advance